# xquery- getting count of those elements, within a single parent, which are not empty

Tags: xquery

Please consider the following XML--

```
<div id="test">
    <p> Text sihdfaif</p>
    <p />
    <p> Text sihdfaif</p>
    <p />
    <p> Text sihdfaif</p>
    <p> Text sihdfaif</p>
    <p> Text sihdfaif</p>
</div>
```

Now, I want to obtain the number of p elements that have some text within them.. in this case, that value=5 (there are 2 'p' elements which are empty)

This is the XQuery that I came up with--

```
    let $claims_main := $doc//div[@id="test"]
        let $claims := $doc//div[@id="test"]/p
        let $n := count($claims)
        where $claims_main/p != '' 
        return $n
```

However the result that I get from the above is7, i.e. including the empty 'p' elements.

An alternative that I thought of, is using a for loop over all of the 'p' elements, but in that case how do I retrieve the total number of elements of the loop? If I use count in that case, then I simply get [1,1,1,1,1]- ie. count of each p element (since in the for loop the count would be for each of the 'p' elements, and not the div itself)...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**As the question asks specifically for "`p` elements that have some text within them",** here is how to get the number of precisely such `p` elements:

```
count(/*/div/p[string(.)])
```

This produces the number of all `p` elements with non-empty string value, that are children of a `div` that is a child of the top element of the XML document.

**In addition, if "non-empty" also means having non white-space-only string value**:

```
count(/*/div/p[normalize-space(.)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
count($doc//div[@id='test']/p[node()])
```

the second predicate `[node()]` selects only elements that contain child nodes, it is equivalent to `[./node()]`.